# Configuring ulimit of `max open files` for daemonized nginx master process

Tags: debian, nginx, ulimit

I have an `nginx`-daemon running on a Debian (8.3). The nginx process occasionally runs into resource limitations when trying to write log files: `too many open files`.

The `nginx` master process is executed with root, while each of the four worker processes is executed with `www-data` user permissions.

When I checked for the nginx-master and each worker process limit configuration I discovered something odd.

```
cat /proc/{nginx-master-process-id}/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
…
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
…

cat /proc/{nginx-any-worker-process-id}/limits
…
Max open files            30000                30000                files
…
```

Each nginx worker is allowed to open 30000 files.

The nginx master process though is only allowed to open 1024 files, respectively 4096 files regarding the hard limit.

When I check for the root user ulimit settings I see no such limit defined! Where does this 1024/4096 setting may come from?

### root ulimit settings

```
# logged in as root
ulimit -H
unlimited
```

Additionally I checked the daemon config:

### /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --signal QUIT --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
# Give Passenger a chance to clean up before being killed by systemd.
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I see no ulimit configuration here, either.

What places else can I check to modify the 1024/4096 nofile limit for the `nginx`-master process?

Comment: Please see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-too-many-open-files/

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849331/how-to-set-nginx-max-open-files

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro My problem is not the nginx error but the fact that the nginx master process has an NOL of 1024.

Answer (score 12):

It seems the *problem*, so to speak, was my wrong assumption that a systemd service respects the ulimit configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

As it turns out a daemon configured via systemd does intentionally ignore settings in the limits.conf and requires a `LimitNOFILE` configuration in the service configuration file.

Updating my systemd unit file fixed the problem:

### /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --signal QUIT --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
# Give Passenger a chance to clean up before being killed by systemd.
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed
LimitNOFILE=30000 # <= This line was added

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here are some links and resources regarding this issue:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/628610/increasing-nproc-for-processes-launched-by-systemd-on-centos-7
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=754285

Thanks to @ijaz-khan for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: Make sure not to copy the commit.  Nginx x can't parse the # <= This line was added

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this, is to either copy the service file

`cp /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system`

and then edit it in `/etc/systemd/system`. In case `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d` exists, a simple override can be made by creating `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/ulimit.conf` with the following content

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=30000
```

Overriding in `/etc` is the recommended way when dealing with systemd definition files. Don't forget to finally `systemctl daemon-reload`